# Getting ApprovalStatus information from ActivityInstance

Tags: 2011, workflow

I am relatively new to SDL Tridion and working on the SDL Tridion 2011 two step workflow process.

I want to get the ApprovalStatus information in the Event System when the Workflow Activity is finished.

Can someone help me and tell me if it is possible to retrieve this information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could directly get the approval status from the Activity Definition.

```
[TcmExtension("ActivityRelatedEvent")]
public class ActivityRelatedEvent : TcmExtension
{
    public ActivityRelatedEvent()
    {
        EventSystem.Subscribe<ActivityInstance, FinishActivityEventArgs>(ActivityFinishedEventHandler, EventPhases.Processed);
    }

    public void ActivityFinishedEventHandler(ActivityInstance activityInstance, FinishActivityEventArgs e, EventPhases phase)
    {
        ApprovalStatus approvalStatus = ((TridionActivityDefinition) activityInstance.ActivityDefinition).FinishApprovalStatus;
        if (approvalStatus != null)
        {
            Logger.Write(approvalStatus.Id.ToString());
            Logger.Write(approvalStatus.Title);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to the Tridion Community and asking a clean question.

To get this information you may try the following Event System code block below:

```cs
private static void WorkflowEvent(ActivityInstance activityInstance, FinishActivityEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
{
    IEnumerable<WorkItem> workItems = activityInstance.WorkItems;
    WorkItem currentWFItem;
    using (IEnumerator<WorkItem> iter = workItems.GetEnumerator())
    {
        iter.MoveNext();
        currentWFItem = iter.Current;
    }

    if (currentWFItem != null)
    {
        Component currentComponent = (Component)currentWFItem.Session.GetObject(currentWFItem.Subject.Id);
        ApprovalStatus approvalStatus = currentComponent.ApprovalStatus;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using LastOrDefault instead of that GetEnumerator loop - or at least simplify it to `foreach (WorkItem item in workitems)` :)

Comment: Agreed Peter; I have copied it from one of my very old post from old tridion forum without realizing the poor performance issue in it